# pandas read_csv error trying to read csv with colon in values

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV files that is using ";" separator. The CSV has this structure in its rows:

```
01/09/22;00:00;1829664;884435280;30256;7618031;827711;9559232
```

Running this code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('\MyCSV.csv', sep=';')
```

I'm getting this error: "Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 3, saw 18"

Doing tests, if I delete the second column that have values with colon ":" (time) it works. So I know that the conflict is in this second column that have time values with a colon character.

Any help to solve it?
Thanks!

Comment: Can You Post line 2 through 4 of your csv ?

Comment: if you created this file CSV then you should change code which writes it.

Comment: `colon` is not problem but rather you have too many `;` - it expects 4 columns (three `;`)` but this line has 18 columns (17 `;`) . It may need to read all as normal text and make corrections on your own. OR you have to correct code which write this file - it should use module `csv` or `pandas` to write data. And it should write the same number of data in every row. If some row doesn't have data then it should write empty elements. In CSV every row should have the same number of columns.

Comment: better show first 3 lines from file - and we will see what really makes problem.

Comment: The data snippet you show has 8 fields and the error message says `"Expected 4 fields in line 3, saw 18"`. So the number of data fields per line in the file is not consistent.